# Angular 7 - leave confirmation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I was wondering if it's possible to trigger a leave confirmation when there is unsaved data on a certain module when the user clicks on a different module within your single page application. And if you could also trigger this when the user refreshes or leaves the webpage. How would you implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) guard is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmation for routing to another module can be easily implemented with [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate).

Refreshing and `x`ing the tab can be a bit trickier. You will have to add listener to a window event `beforeunload`.

Something like this could work for a given component:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
unloadHandler(event: Event) {
    // Your logic on beforeunload
}
```